# FRUSTRATED R PROGRAMMER?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am a intermediate level programmer, interested in ML generally.

RE: Decision Tree Classifier with iris data.

In R this is so easy .. I inspect the raw data in the .csv file and THEN upload to R dataframe for preprocessing, etc.

In Python with sklearn this is just hellishly DIFFICULT !
I do NOT want to just use `iris = datasets.load_iris()`

I want to LOAD MY OWN IRIS DATA from the .csv file via a pandas dataframe and preprocess.  Then I want to load selected pandas dataframe features & target columns into sklearn  WHILE PRESERVING THE COLUMN HEADER NAMES (?need to use bunch)

With correct syntax, I've tried & failed:

- `df.values`
- `df.to_matrix()`
- `np.array(df)`
- `df.to_records()` .. headers preserved BUT INDEX stops it being loaded into sklearn .. will try `index=False` .. but not optimistic.
- also tried loading dataframe slices directly to sklearn with no joy.

I have read all the web resources + discussed it at my local computerGroup with absolutely NO success

sklearn looks great .. BUT as soon as you want to load your own data it's PAINFUL !    Why is this so hard to do in Python ?

Please Can someone just post some code that works + include all dependencies please.

Best Regards, but in pain,
David

Comment: Sorry the *   in  * df.values  is not code .. just highlighting what I've tried

Comment: try this question on stackoverflow. They are better suited to help you with this. I'm voting to move this question there. They're going to want to see code you've tried.

Comment: I/O is clearly not within the scope here, BTW, Python is open source, piece of cake, lots of users. Put this on programming site, I also flagged for a move.

Comment: @dkc Off-topic here; see the [help/on-topic] (even if it was on topic it would close on several other grounds). This can't be migrated to somewhere like SO because in its current form it would quickly close there. See the [SO help/on-topic](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for the code that was posted,  it works OK  however the  dataframe COLUMN NAMES are NOT passed into the model.
..

Comment: So when I print the Decision Tree the variables are  V1 & V2 etc

I hoped for feature names like "Sepal.Length" etc  and  target named "Species"  in the Decision Tree output from the classifier model.

And yes .. I will send this query to stackoverflow.

Thanks again, David

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to read your data into pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")
```

As for preprocessing, you must tell us what you want before we can be any more specific. Next, create a new classifier:

```
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

Select the features and the target (replace the "col" things with real column names):

```
features = df[["col1","col2","col3"]]
target = df["target"]
```

And train the model:

```
clf.fit(features, target)
```

[More about trees...](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html%20More%20about%20trees...)